# EF Core, A second operation started on this context, Context Inhertiance reuse connections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying understand how to create a context with two lifetimes, I'm running async code and I need to separate my contexts so they don't run under the same connection, EntityFramework However, seems to be reusing connections on separate contexts, which is causing this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed.

In my `StartUp` I register two contexts:

```
string connection = @"Server=localhost;Database=Custom;Trusted_Connection=True;";

services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<CustomContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(connection))
        // I've also tried without this, it's weird but it still maps
        .AddDbContext<IsolatedCustomContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

services.AddTransient<DbContext, CustomContext>();
services.AddTransient<IsolatedCustomContext>();
```

My isolated context is a the same as the custom context so I've declared like so:

```
public class IsolatedCustomContext : CustomContext
{
    public IsolatedCustomContext(DbContextOptions<CustomContext> options,
        DbAuthorizationOptions<CustomContext> authorizationOptions, 
        IMemoryCache memoryCache) : base(options, authorizationOptions, memoryCache)
    {
    }
}
```

and my custom context is declared like so:

```
public partial class CustomContext: DbContext
{
    public CustomContext(DbContextOptions<CustomContext> options,
         DbAuthorizationOptions<CustomContext> authorizationOptions, IMemoryCache memoryCache) : base(options, authorizationOptions, memoryCache)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Startup` I sync the user profile with my identity server like so:

```
o.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnTokenValidated = async tvc => { await AuthenticationRule.ValidateToken(tvc); }
};
```

My authentication uses the isolated context to update user info:

```
// Using shouldn't be required but I've tried with it and without it
using (var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IsolatedAstootContext>())
{
    var userId = await context.Users
                              .Where(u => u.UniqueIdentifier == subjectId)
                              .Select(x => x.Id)
                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Looks like the Pipeline Split's and runs concurrently after the token is validate to execute the request  I have a controller that looks like so:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public UsersController : Controller
{
     CustomContext _context;

     public UsersController(CustomContext context)
     {
          this._context = context;
     }

     [HttpGet]
     public User GetCurrentUser()
     {
         var userId = User.GetUserIdFromClaims();
         return this._context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
     }
}
```

When I call `GetCurrentUser`, I get the concurrency error,  I can see in the call stack it has not exited the isolated context using still. What's weird is they are two separate contexts.

is it possible that by inheriting context, EntityFrameWork is Viewing this context as the same and some how reusing the connection?

Does anyone know how I can register these so they can operate parallel over different connections?

Comment: In the DB context classes, constructor names don't match the class names -- are those typos?

Comment: @felix-b yeah sorry i was trying to simplify the example

Comment: EF core make use of a connection pool to speed up sth. I don't know if it is related so it's only for your reference.

Comment: @Lol interesting I'll take a look maybe I need to do some additional configuration.

Comment: wow I never knew you can even do this. try adding private readonly CustomContext _context; in the controller variable may encapsulate it.

Comment: (might not solve your problem, but) Do you need the `services.AddTransient<dbcontexts>`, considering that `AddDbContext` should already register them as transient?

Comment: @Balah Thanks, Yeah I've tried with both. I only added it to the solution for the sake of completeness

Comment: I'm not sure if this will solve my problem but I did see my Connection string should be [marked async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.asynchronousprocessing.aspx) which I never did explicitly

Comment: Never mind that is not required anymore

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging on entityframework Core GitHub and found this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7533)

It looks like this was cause by the DbOptions through Inheritance in order to fix this I need to hide a protected constructor

```
public partial class CustomContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomContext(DbContextOptions<CustomContext> options,
         DbAuthorizationOptions<CustomContext> authorizationOptions, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
         : base(options, authorizationOptions, memoryCache)
    {
    }

    protected CustomContext(DbContextOptions options,
         DbAuthorizationOptions<CustomContext> authorizationOptions, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
         : base(options, authorizationOptions, memoryCache)
    {
    }
}
```

Then in I can call the protected constructor from my Isolated Context:

```
public class IsolatedContext : CustomContext
{
    public IsolatedAstootContext(DbContextOptions<IsolatedCustomContext> options,
        DbAuthorizationOptions<CustomContext> authorizationOptions, 
        IMemoryCache memoryCache) : base(options, authorizationOptions, memoryCache)
    {
    }
}
```